# Is it possible to check whether a user has access to Spotify for Artists for a specific artist?

Tags: spotify

I am trying to automatically verify that a user is a particular Spotify artist (or at least on the artist's team). The problem is that an artist and a user are different. Spotify's authentication API deals with user accounts. However, [user accounts](https://artists.spotify.com/faq/verification#do-i-have-to-use-my-personal-spotify-account) are used to access Spotify for Artists and are internally verified by Spotify.

Therefore, it looks like I just need some way to check whether the user can access the artist. Is there any API or other way to check that a particular authenticated user is tied to a Spotify for Artists account?

Comment: Hi Brian, I am trying to do the same thing. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Sorry Douglas, I did not. As far as I’m aware this is still not possible.

Comment: I am trying to list track of the profile, so if it's an artists it has tracks... or not?